How is my x86_64 machine is running an arm64 binary?
My machine's architecture is x86_64 and I've cross-compiled arm64 assembly (from here) into an executable. However the binary is still runnable on my machine... how?
Here are the outputs to the following commands:
$ uname -r 
6.2.12-100.fc36.x86_64

$ file hello
hello: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, ARM aarch64, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, stripped

$ ./hello
Hello, ARM64

$ qemu-aarch64-static hello
Hello, ARM64

$ qemu-x86_64-static hello
qemu-x86_64-static: hello: Invalid ELF image for this architecture

$ readelf -a hello 
ELF Header:
  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 02 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
  Class:                             ELF64
  Data:                              2's complement, little endian
  Version:                           1 (current)
  OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
  ABI Version:                       0
  Type:                              EXEC (Executable file)
  Machine:                           AArch64
  Version:                           0x1
  Entry point address:               0x4000b0
  Start of program headers:          64 (bytes into file)
  Start of section headers:          264 (bytes into file)
  Flags:                             0x0
  Size of this header:               64 (bytes)
  Size of program headers:           56 (bytes)
  Number of program headers:         2
  Size of section headers:           64 (bytes)
  Number of section headers:         4
  Section header string table index: 3

Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type             Address           Offset
       Size              EntSize          Flags  Link  Info  Align
  [ 0]                   NULL             0000000000000000  00000000
       0000000000000000  0000000000000000           0     0     0
  [ 1] .text             PROGBITS         00000000004000b0  000000b0
       0000000000000030  0000000000000000  AX       0     0     8
  [ 2] .data             PROGBITS         00000000004100e0  000000e0
       000000000000000d  0000000000000000  WA       0     0     1
  [ 3] .shstrtab         STRTAB           0000000000000000  000000ed
       0000000000000017  0000000000000000           0     0     1
Key to Flags:
  W (write), A (alloc), X (execute), M (merge), S (strings), I (info),
  L (link order), O (extra OS processing required), G (group), T (TLS),
  C (compressed), x (unknown), o (OS specific), E (exclude),
  D (mbind), p (processor specific)

There are no section groups in this file.

Program Headers:
  Type           Offset             VirtAddr           PhysAddr
                 FileSiz            MemSiz              Flags  Align
  LOAD           0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000400000 0x0000000000400000
                 0x00000000000000e0 0x00000000000000e0  R E    0x10000
  LOAD           0x00000000000000e0 0x00000000004100e0 0x00000000004100e0
                 0x000000000000000d 0x000000000000000d  RW     0x10000

 Section to Segment mapping:
  Segment Sections...
   00     .text 
   01     .data 

There is no dynamic section in this file.

There are no relocations in this file.

The decoding of unwind sections for machine type AArch64 is not currently supported.

No version information found in this file.





ls /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/qemu*aarch*

awesome, thank you.

To make an executable in unix, you make the file executable with chmod +x.
Of course, for this to work, the system has to know how to run it.
If it's a text file, it might assume it is a shell script and run it with bash or sh.
But if you're doing it right, you would put at the top of your shell script
#!/bin/bash

which explicitly tells unix that this file was meant to be interpreted with bash.  Turns out you can put any binary name up there as long as it can take a text file as an input and either ignore the first line or ignore lines starting with #.  You can do this, for instance, with perl, awk, python, etc...
You could consider the first two characters of the file (#!) to be a "magic number" identifying this as a script, with the path to the interpreter following that.
Linux took this a step further.  It has a system (binfmt_misc) where you can describe arbitrary magic numbers for any executable format and rather than have the interpreter name in the file explicitly, you can assign an arbitrary interpreter to an arbitrary magic number identifier.
For instance, it is possible to identify java files and run them directly as if they were normal executables and have the system automatically invoke them with the java interpreter.
Turns out this is used even for normal executables.  So if you say
$ file /bin/ls

you might get

/bin/ls: ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV),
dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for
GNU/Linux 3.2.0, stripped

So the "interpreter" for a normal executable is /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
(Side note: I don't think file knows about binfmt_misc, it has its own magic number database that includes a lot that binfmt_misc might not know.)
If you go ahead and install an emulator for another cpu, say qemu, it's not too difficult to just add the magic numbers to binfmt_misc for the executable formats qemu knows how to deal with, and then poof magically executables for that interpreter run as if they were native executables....just like shell scripts.

Sweet, thank you. I can see the binfmts listed at the path dave_thompson listed above.
